# How to add users in organic groups using services Rest api?

Tags: 7, services

I'm having problem while adding users in organic group. Here I'm trying to add user in organic group called "Supervisor", I'm using following json and Rest api :

```
Json :
{ "title":"Supervisor",
  "type":"group",
  "og_group_ref": { "und": [{ "target_id": "1921" }]},
  "field_records": { "und": [{ "value": "5" }]}
}
```

Rest api :
http://localhost/dev/test/node/1921

but, above json and api is not working, am I using correct json and rest api ?

Comment: The rest api which you are using will display only the node properties. It will not add the users to the group. Instead of this, you need to create your custom rest service callback and link the og group to the user, since og not providing any rest calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/og_services
2. Go to `admin/structure/services/list/[MY-ENDPOINT]/resources`
3. Enable at minimum the `join` resource
4. Flush all of Drupal's caches
5. Make a `POST` call to `[MY-ENDPOINT]/og/join/[GROUP-NID]/[USER-UID]`

Comment: Thank you, "og_services" module is working, now I am able add multiple users in any group.

Answer (score 0):

I think this what you need

```
/*
 * Implements hook_services_resources
 */
function your_module_name_services_resources() {
  return array(
    'add_user' => array(
      'create' => array(
        'help' => 'Add users to group',
        'callback' => 'your_module_add_user_to_group',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'access arguments append' => TRUE,
        'args' => array(
          array(
            'name' => 'uid',
            'type' => 'id',
            'description' => 'The uid of the user to add in group',
            'source' => array('data' => 'uid'),
            'optional' => FALSE,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

/*
 * Call back to add the user
 */
function your_module_add_user_to_group($uid) {
  $user_account = user_load($uid);
  $og_values = array(
     'entity_type' => 'user',
     'entity' => $user_account,
     'state' => OG_STATE_ACTIVE,
   );
   //This is will add the group to the user.
  og_group('node', $your_group_nid, $og_values);
  user_save($user_account);
  return success;
}
```

Put this code in your custom module file. And go to "**Structure->service->your_end_point->enable 'add_user' resources**"

Then call
  **url : http://localhost.com/endpoint/add_user**

**method: POST**

**In data field data: uid=595 (pass the user id for whom you need to add the group);**

I think this will do the trick.